# Angular patchValue not working with JsonConverter

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

I have a angular form with a select control which receives it's values from an enum on the server.

```
<select name="" id="" [formControl]="form.get('myType')">
  <option *ngFor="let type of types"  [value]="+type['key']">
    {{ type['value'] }} ({{  type['key']}})
  </option>
</select>
```

I've created an example here with the response hard coded in the types variable : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kckeuf)

I'm now trying to populate the form using the form patchValue method (see setValues button and method).

```
  setValues() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      myType: 0
    });
  }
```

In real life this response comes form the server.

The model from the server is as follows:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public MyType Type { get; set; }
}
```

So far this works.

If I change the model on the server to include the Json StringEnumConverter attribute:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public MyType Type { get; set; }
}
```

The patchValue method is now like this (see setValues2 button and method):

```
  setValues2() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      myType: 'Type1'
    });
  }
```

However my value is no longer loaded into the select control.

How can I get around this?

I started creating a directive but I don't know how to intercept the bindings to change the value to the enums key equivalent.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have set option value as ***key*** property from **types** array

```
<option *ngFor="let type of types"  [value]="+type['key']">
```

But in **setValues2** method you set form value as **type['value']**, that's why this method doesn't work. As it expects values **1** or **2**, but gets **Type2**.

I think you can try to set option's value as object from types array

```
<option *ngFor="let type of types"  [value]="type">
```

then your methods should set these objects as form value

```
setValues() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      myType: this.types[0]
    });
  }

  setValues2() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      myType: this.types[1]
    });
  }
```

Comment: I was hoping to create a directive as some of the endpoint models have the Json string converter and some dont

Comment: Probably I don't get the case for which you need a directive, but as long as you assign option's value as whole object, it doesn't matter what properties this object has

Answer (score 0):

As your selected item is based on `key`, however, there is no `key` with value `Type1`. So your `[value]` is null. You can find its key by `value` and set `[value]`:

```
setValues2() {
   this.form.patchValue({
      myType: this.getKey('Type1')
   });
}

getKey(typeName:string) {
    let key = this.types.find(f => f.value === typeName).key;
    return key ? key : 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is sort of what I want but I want a directive to intercept the setting of the value. The reason I'd like a directive is because I have multiple forms that will have similar code, the patchValue call is within a base class so the type will be different for each form.